# REST JSON, Server lmit of 50 records, get all records (updated with current example)

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

I'm using a REST API to get JSON.  The owner has imposed a limit of 50 results.  Can someone suggest any links / tutorials on how I can get all the records and then derserialisze them into list?

I'm using RestSharp & C#

Since posting this question yesterday I have tried to work through a solution which creates a new method which can be used accross all REST calls.  What I have is this:

```
    public T getAllRecords<T>(List<T> genericList, string RestCommand, string[,] parameters)
    {

        int pageCount = 50;
        var client = new RestClient("https://******************************");
        client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("*******", "*******");

        var request = new RestRequest(RestCommand, Method.GET);
        // add the parameters
        for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length / 2; i++)
        {
            request.AddParameter(parameters[i, 0], parameters[i, 1]);
        }


            var response = client.Execute(request);
        var content = response.Content;

        if (typeof(T) == typeof(Rootobject))
        {
            List<Rootobject> tempObject = new List<Rootobject>();
            tempObject.Cast<Rootobject>();
            Rootobject myRel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(content);
            tempObject.Add(myRel);

            // create logic for looping through remaining records
            int totalRecords = myRel.meta.pageInfo.totalResults;
            do
            {
                request.AddParameter("startAt", pageCount);
                response = client.Execute(request);
                content = response.Content;
                Rootobject myRel1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(content);
                tempObject.Add(myRel1);
                pageCount += 50;
            } while (pageCount <= totalRecords);

            List<Item.Datum> totalList = new List<Item.Datum>();
            foreach (Rootobject rootItem in tempObject)
            {
                foreach (Item.Datum item in rootItem.data)
                {
                    totalList.Add(item);
                }
            }

            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(totalList, typeof(Item.Datum));


        }

        return default(T);

    }
```

I call it like this:

```
var allItems = getAllRecords(new List<Rootobject>(), "abstractitems", new string[,] { { "project", "001" }, { "itemType", "151" }, { "maxResults", "50" } });
```

I was expecting it to retun a list of objects of type **Item.Datum**, however it errors with the error:

System.InvalidCastException: 'Object must implement IConvertible.'

I've just about reached the limit of my current understanding, appreciate any pointers as to how to get this over the finish line.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please provide a bit more detail? Such responses typically include the total number of records and you would continue to query while increasing the requested page number until you have everything. i.e. `/api/items?page=1`, `/api/items?page=2`, etc.

Comment: Please read: https://dev.jamasoftware.com/rest#lists The API supports paging. You just need to send a `startAt` parameter.

Comment: the docu states that a max of 50 records is implemented on the lists. https://dev.jamasoftware.com/rest#lists

Comment: My interpretation is that you can retrieve 50 items *per request* and make subsequent requests to get the rest of the data, each time incrementing the `startAt` parameter to an appropriate value. You will need some kind of a loop for this.

Answer (score 0):

As [this](https://dev.jamasoftware.com/rest#lists) explains Jama SaaS APIs allow a maximum of 50 records to be returned, you will have to make multiple calls if you want more than those 50 records. This can be done with a simple `for` loop.

Comment: I know you don't have enough rep to comment on questions yet but you've posted an answer that doesn't actually attempt to answer the users question, so I'm flagging this as such.

Comment: @RomanMarusyk I updated my answer, and as far as I know provided the answer